# jqPlot ticks without decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am using jqplot, and it gets marks by default like this:

[image: jqplot screenshot]

What should I do to get it without `.0` at the end?

Comment: Perhaps you want to set `stringFormat`: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-highlighter-js.html#$.jqplot.Highlighter.formatString. `%d` would represent a signed integer.

Comment: Thanks!If someone wants to do it, this is piece of code    axes:{
          xaxis:{min:0, max:31,
          tickOptions: {
           formatString:'%d'
            },
      },

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since it was indeed the answer I'll post it as an actual one.

With [`stringFormat`](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-highlighter-js.html#%24.jqplot.Highlighter.formatString), you can format the string of the axis labels, and it uses `sprintf` notation, where `%d` is a signed integer. Since integers do not have decimals, it is probably what you want.

Comment: This sort of works. Since it doesn't hide non-whole numbers, only changes their values, a problem arises on axes with a small range. Instead of `0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0...` you will see `0, 1, 1, 2, 2...`